# JavaScript: How to reuse the "Working on it..." pop in

Tags: 2013, javascript, modal-dialog, ajax

Sharepoint 2013: In have custom JavaScript code that makes Ajax calls. While loading I'd like to show Sharepoint's loading pop in:

[image: working_on_it]

That is the one that greys out the underlying page and centers a loading box with shadows.

Any hint how to call the "show" function and the "remove" function as soon as my Ajax completes?

Thanks,
 Juergen

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Juergen,

The below article should help:
http://www.collabware.com/blog/2013/03/22/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialogs

You have [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408140.aspx) which can be used..

```
function RequestEnded(sender, args) {
  try {
    waitDialog.close();
    waitDialog = null;
  } catch (ex) { }
};

function RequestStarted(sender, args) {
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowWaitDialog, "sp.js");
};

function ShowWaitDialog() {
   try {
      if (waitDialog == null) {
         waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', 'Please wait while request is in progress...', 76, 330);
      }
   } catch (ex) { }
};
```

Comment: Arsalan, thanks a lot! Works like charm! All I needed was `oLoader = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);` and `oLoader.close();` Brilliant!

Comment: Mentioned URL isn't working http://blog.collabware.com/2013/03/22/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialogs/

Comment: @Yayati I have updated the URL: http://www.collabware.com/blog/2013/03/22/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialogs

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Much thanks for prompt response. :)

Comment: I love you so much

Comment: @NderonHyseni thanks but no thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

//show and hide waiting on it javascript

```
    function waitMessage() {
        window.parent.eval("window.waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', '', 90, 300);");
    }

    function closeMessage() {
        if (window.frameElement != null) {
            if (window.parent.waitDialog != null) {
                window.parent.waitDialog.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

u can use this $.ShowProcessing("Refreshing Collections...");

Comment: There is no `ShowProcessingmethod` on `$` by default