# SP Long operation notifications in SharePoint Hosted apps

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, splongoperation

Is it possible to implement SPLongOperation (or equivalent) in SharePoint Hosted apps, to use the SP default "Working on it.." dialog until list operations are completed?

Comment: [This](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88905/javascript-how-to-reuse-the-working-on-it-pop-in) question here has an answer, but I don't think it'll work in an App (last I tried, I couldn't use a modal in a SP-hosted app).  You can give it a try though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to reuse the "working on it" dialog in apps.

The following loads the wait screen when List operations start executing.

- SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);

Once the operations are complete I use

- SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();

Got a reference from this - [JavaScript: How to reuse the "Working on it..." pop in](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88905/javascript-how-to-reuse-the-working-on-it-pop-in?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement SPLongOperation in SharePoint hosted apps and probably there is out of the box feature available for SPLongOperation equivalent feature.

The workaround could be you can use JavaScript/jQuery plugin for this. There are lot available like spin.js.

Comment: Yes i thought of this approach and built a modal dialog using twitter bootstrap 3, as i'm making use of it already in my application. Just wanted to know if it is possible at all. Thanks