# how to show the progress bar while binding data from sharepoint list to html table

Tags: javascript, jsom, html5

- I had drop down's and based no that I am binding the data to html
  table from SharePoint list.

  - My Customer is expecting to show the progress bar .

Can any one help me how can I show it on page load and also while filtering it from dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Different ways:

1. You can use standard sharepoint loading window for client side, look this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88905/javascript-how-to-reuse-the-working-on-it-pop-in).
2. You can create your own progress bar via javascript, look this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp).
3. You can use long operations for serve side, look [here](https://nikpatel.net/2011/04/27/use-splongoperation-to-display-sharepoint-processing-page-for-lengthy-operations/).

Comment: +1 for SPLongOperation. Learned something new.