# SP.UI.ModalDialog Not working

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

I would like to show SP.UI.ModalDialog until I process and bind the data to data table.
Can any one please do let me know what's wrong in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("Hello World");
    var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', 'Request is in progress...' );
        function1();function2();function3();
        dialog .close();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    function RequestEnded() {
        try {
            waitDialog.close();
            waitDialog = null;
        } catch (ex) {}
    };

    function RequestStarted() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowWaitDialog, "sp.js");
    };

    function ShowWaitDialog() {
        try {
            if (waitDialog == null) {
                waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', 'Please wait while request is in progress...', 76, 330);
            }
        } catch (ex) {}
    };

    function BindTable() {
        RequestStarted();
        //Logic to bind the table
        RequestEnded();
    }
```

Ref: [Use showWaitScreenWithNoClose](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88905/javascript-how-to-reuse-the-working-on-it-pop-in)
[How to open or close SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose](https://sharepointweblog.blogspot.in/2014/08/sharepoint-2013-how-to-open-and-close.html)

All the best!!!